# RxAndroid Release Apk is not working for build 25.0.2

Tags: android, basic-authentication, retrofit2, rx-android, rx-java2

I have posted this on [rxandroid issue page](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/issues/350#issuecomment-272271772) too but no response its been 4 days but no response ,  problem is in debug apk rxjava functionalities are working as expected , but in release apk , only functionalities related to rxjava or rxandroid are not working at all

**build.gradle(project)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' //or apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
def AAVersion = '4.1.0'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jutt.example1"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled false
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources false
            zipAlignEnabled true
            //debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }

}

apt {
    arguments {
        // you should set your package name here if you are using different application IDs
        // resourcePackageName "your.package.name"

        // You can set optional annotation processing options here, like these commented options:
        // logLevel 'INFO'
        // logFile '/var/log/aa.log'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    // Retrofit & OkHttp
    // Because RxAndroid releases are few and far between, it is recommended you also
// explicitly depend on RxJava's latest version for bug fixes and new features.

// If you want to bind to Android-specific lifecycles

// If you want pre-written Activities and Fragments you can subclass as providers
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    //compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.5.0'
    //compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    //compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.2'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.trello.rxlifecycle2:rxlifecycle:2.0.1'
}
```

**build.gradle(module)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-beta2'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        // replace with the current version of the android-apt plugin
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**progaurd:**

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in /Users/zulqurnainjutt/Library/Android/sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

-optimizationpasses 5
#-allowaccessmodification
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose

#your package path where your gson models are stored
-keep class com.jutt.example1.model.** { *; }

# Retrofit, OkHttp, Gson
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Signature
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn rx.**
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-dontwarn java.nio.file.*
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement

# OkHttp3
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }
-dontwarn okhttp3.**

# Rxjava-promises

-keep class com.darylteo.rx.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.darylteo.rx.**

# RxJava 0.21

-keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers {
    public static <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.ImmediateScheduler {
    public <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.TestScheduler {
    public <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers {
    public static ** test();
}

## Retrolambda specific rules ##

# as per official recommendation: https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda#proguard
-dontwarn java.lang.invoke.*
```

Stack Trace when network call is gone :

```
com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.HttpException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized
01-22 19:24:14.872 11502-11502/? W/System.err:     at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable$BodyObserver.onNext(BodyObservable.java:54)
01-22 19:24:14.872 11502-11502/? W/System.err:     at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable$BodyObserver.onNext(BodyObservable.java:37)
01-22 19:24:14.872 11502-11502/? W/System.err:     at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallObservable.subscribeActual(CallObservable.java:43)
01-22 19:24:14.872 11502-11502/? W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10514)
01-22 19:24:14.872 11502-11502/? W/System.err:     at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
01-22 19:24:14.872 11502-11502/? W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10514)
01-22 19:24:14.872 11502-11502/? W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnLifecycle.subscribeActual(ObservableDoOnLifecycle.java:33)
01-22 19:24:14.872 11502-11502/? W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10514)
01-22 19:24:14.872 11502-11502/? W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach.subscribeActual(ObservableDoOnEach.java:42)
01-22 19:24:14.872 11502-11502/? W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10514)
01-22 19:24:14.872 11502-11502/? W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn.subscribeActual(ObservableObserveOn.java:44)
01-22 19:24:14.872 11502-11502/? W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10514)
01-22 19:24:14.872 11502-11502/? W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$1.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:39)
01-22 19:24:14.872 11502-11502/? W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Scheduler$1.run(Scheduler.java:134)
01-22 19:24:14.872 11502-11502/? W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:59)
01-22 19:24:14.872 11502-11502/? W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:51)
01-22 19:24:14.872 11502-11502/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
01-22 19:24:14.872 11502-11502/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
01-22 19:24:14.872 11502-11502/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
01-22 19:24:14.872 11502-11502/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1115)
01-22 19:24:14.872 11502-11502/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:590)
01-22 19:24:14.872 11502-11502/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**Updates:**
As far as i'm able to figure out is that i'm using Basic authentication in my factory class of Retrofit , i think problem lies in Basic authentication, but i am unable to fix it.

Any possible solution ?

Comment: It is definitely because of proguard. Just add `minifyEnabled true` in your debug build and post strack trace of exception.

Comment: In your `build.gradle` it's not true. Im talking about debug build.

Comment: your point is unclear @Divers

Comment: I need to see stacktrace in order to help you. In order to archive that, you need to enable code minification for debug builds and run app.

Comment: how can i minify in debug ?

Comment: @ZulqurnainJutt When you compile you get a list of `Warning: ...` in the output. We need to see that. Copy it here.

Comment: @Divers Stack trace from the build process is useless most of the time, including this instance. We need to see proguard output.

Comment: i don't get any warning..

Comment: added stacktrace and it got some errors

Comment: Since when RxJava is the problem that you get 401 - Unauthorized? Are you even thing of it?

Comment: it is not rxjava problem only , it is configuration problem of retrofit 2 with rxjava to run RxAdapterFactory , which is basically doing Basic authentication in application

Comment: can you post the class which you create your retrofit api? thanks.

Comment: @ZulqurnainJutt did you end up with any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
-keep class rx.internal.util.unsafe.** {
    *;
 }
```

to your proguard file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting late answer but solution was to use https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter 
And setup factory class of retrofit accordingly

Note: rxjava 2 only support retrofit 2 vice versa

Source : experience