# Android App Crash : retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 401

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

[image]Sometimes in API response, I get **401 Unauthorised status code.** I tried to handle this here in my **networkInterceptor**, but still app crashes. Don't know what I am doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Here is my RetrofitFactory Class

```
object RetrofitFactory {

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(
        OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
            .addInterceptor(
                object : Interceptor {
                    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
                            val request: Request = chain.request()
                                .newBuilder()
                                .build()
                            return chain.proceed(request)
                    }
                }
            )
            .addNetworkInterceptor(
                Interceptor { chain ->
                    val original = chain.request()
                    val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                    val request = requestBuilder.build()
                    val response = chain.proceed(request)
                    Log.e("request", request.headers.toString())
                    Log.e("Response Body", response.body!!.toString())
                    when (response.code) {
                        HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK -> return@Interceptor response
                        HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED -> sessionExpired(
                            BaseApplication.getApplication()
                        )
                        HttpURLConnection.HTTP_FORBIDDEN -> sessionExpired(
                            BaseApplication.getApplication()
                        )
                    }
                    response
                }
            )
            .build()
    )
    .build()

@JvmStatic
fun <S> createService(serviceClass: Class<S>): S {
    return retrofit.create(serviceClass)
}
}
```

I want to move the user to Login Screen. So here is the function that should be called, but isn't calling.

```
fun sessionExpired(application: Application) {
    val intent = Intent(application, LogInActivity::class.java)
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    application.startActivity(intent)
}
```

And here are my dependencies:

```
//retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.2'
//logging interceptor
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.4.0"
```

I also did look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41806148/8874958) and many other similar questions, but didn't find help!

**UPDATE ABOUT HOW I AM CALLING API:**

in viewmodel with this

```
 viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val apiResponse = apiEndPointsInterface.loginUser(loginRequestModel)
        returnLoginResponse(apiResponse)
    }
```

and the APIEndPointInterface is this

```
@POST(AppConstants.APIEndPoints.LOGIN_USER)
    suspend fun loginUser(
        @Body requestLoginModel: LoginRequestModel
    ): LoginResponseModel
```

Comment: Can you please post the complete logcat?

Answer (score 3):

You should call sessionExpired function in onFailure method the retrofit request.

```
override fun onFailure(call: Call<Model.Result>, t: Throwable) {
                if(t is HttpException && t.statusCode==401)
                    sessionExpired(BaseApplication.getApplication())
            }
```

If you are using Kotlin coroutines. You should wrap the await call in try catch block and call the function in catch block. See the below code:

```
val response: String
    val getPlacesDeferred = PlaceAPI.retrofitService.getPlacesAsync()
        response = getPlacesDeferred.await())
        } catch (exception:Exception) {
            if(exception is HttpException && t.statusCode==401)
               sessionExpired(BaseApplication.getApplication())
        }
```

Comment: Where do I have to add this function ?

Comment: In the class where you are calling enqueue on the Call object. Post the code I will tell you.

Comment: I am using Coroutines with suspend function

Comment: Using deferred right? Can you please share  the code?

Comment: You have to catch the error thrown by loginUser. You can wrap it in try catch block.  `viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try{val apiResponse = apiEndPointsInterface.loginUser(loginRequestModel)
        returnLoginResponse(apiResponse)}
        catch(exception:Exception) {if(exception is HttpException && t.statusCode==401)
               sessionExpired(BaseApplication.getApplication())}
    }`

Comment: Perfect! This solved my issue! Thanks a lot. Really appreciate :)

Comment: Works. But I don't like it. I have to do countless network calls and don't want a clone army for exception handling. Before I was forced to use Retrofit I had my own network base class that did all error handling and I want to achieve a similar solution now. I don't want to check for 401 a hundred times - I want to do it's handling once. I thought that I can do this with the interceptors but it doesn't seem so. I don't like the approach with result wrappers but it seems to be the only way if I don't want to use yet another 3rd party library with possibly more problems...

Answer (score 0):

To solve this kind of problems while making any api call or using retrofit. You must use cache strategy.Use Retrofit and Okhttp to solve your problem. It also helps you to prevent anywanted app crash during api calls, even your app not connected to internet.

Comment: I'm sorry, what?